# Using repo package with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to use a custom binary from a repo in lambda (zbartools)  which i can get on the base ami by doing a sudo yum install zbar, however there are  several dependencies

How would i go about replicating this into the lambda enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to package up all the dependencies in the Lambda deployment zip file. This is a good tutorial: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/